# Can someone explain the Tensorflow code below?

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.x

I have been trying to understand the below code (written in Tensorflow), but unable to do so as I am not very proficient with Tensorflow. I am looking for some help. Below is the code:

```
    if model == 'mse':
        rec_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(img, img_rec)
        kld_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(0.5 * (1 + z_log_sigma_sq - z_mu ** 2 - tf.exp(z_log_sigma_sq)))
    else:
        if model == 'gaussian':
            log_sigma = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)
        elif model == 'sigma':
            log_sigma = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=True)
        elif model == 'optimal':
            log_sigma = tf.log(tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean((img - img_rec) ** 2, [0, 1, 2, 3], keepdims=True)))

        rec_loss = tf.reduce_sum(gaussian_nll(img_rec, log_sigma, img))
```

Where the `gaussian_nll` function is defined below:

```
def gaussian_nll(mu, log_sigma, x):
    return 0.5 * ((x - mu) / tf.exp(log_sigma)) ** 2 + log_sigma + 0.5 * np.log(2 * np.pi)
```

I have these questions:

1. What is the difference between `log_sigma` under `model == 'gaussian'` and under `model == 'sigma'`? (only difference in the definition of the variable is the flag `trainable`)
2. What is the difference between the `tf.losses.mean_squared_error` under the `model=='mse'` and `log_sigma` under `model == 'optimal'`? Aren't they both similar?

They are correct, but I am unable to correctly read it. Any help regarding the code would be greatly appreciated. For those of you who wants to take a look at the full code on github, here is the link [github page](https://github.com/orybkin/sigma-vae-tensorflow/blob/7152ace148dbb39555c62e2da5b14c6268ad4696/model.py#L104) (the above piece of code appears between lines 34 and 44)

Thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`gaussian` is different from `sigma`, because `sigma` is trainable while `gaussian` is not. It implies that the value of `sigma` can be optimized but not of `gaussian`.

`optimal` is different from `mse` as

- in the case of mse, the final loss is computed as MSE.
- but in the case of optimal, we use gaussian as the loss function, with MSE acting as the variance of the gaussian kernel.